# Interfaces, Subclasses, Inheritance

Tags: java

I have been working on an assignment which implements a banking transaction processor. I am trying to print an error message when a negative deposit gets applied. 
Beginning of the code

```
import java.util.ArrayList ;

public class TransactionProcessorTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // the account list
        ArrayList<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<>();

        bankAccounts.add(new CheckingAccount    ("chk001",  500.00)) ;
        bankAccounts.add(new SavingsAccount     ("sav001", 5000.00)) ;
        bankAccounts.add(new CheckingAccount    ("chk002",  299.00)) ;
        bankAccounts.add(new SavingsAccount     ("sav002", 9049.00)) ;

        // trhe transation list
        ArrayList<Transaction> transactionList = new ArrayList<>() ;

            // deposit into each type of account
        transactionList.add(new DepositTransaction   ("chk001",  500.00)) ;
        transactionList.add(new DepositTransaction   ("sav001", 5000.00)) ;
        transactionList.add(new DepositTransaction   ("loc001",  350.00)) ;


        // the transaction processor
//      TransactionProcessor transProcessor = new TransactionProcessor() ;

        // print out the bank accounts before applying the transactions
        System.out.println("Bank Account Balances Before Processing Transactions:") ;
        System.out.println("=====================================================") ;
        for (BankAccount acct : bankAccounts)
            System.out.println(acct) ;
        System.out.println("\n") ;

        // process the transactions
        System.out.println("Processing Transactions:") ;
        System.out.println("========================") ;

//      boolean clean = transProcessor.processTransactions(bankAccounts,transactionList) ;
// remove the following line if you uncomment the previous line
boolean clean = true ;

for(Transaction t : transactionList)
    System.out.println(t);

BankAccount test = bankAccounts.get(0)
           ,test1 = bankAccounts.get(1);
Transaction t0 = transactionList.get(0)
           ,t1 = transactionList.get(1)
           ,t3 = transactionList.get(3);

t0.applyTransaction(test);
t3.applyTransaction(test);
t1.applyTransaction(test1);



        System.out.printf("\nThere were %s encountered during transaction processing.%n"
                         ,(clean ? "no errors" : "ERRORS")
                         ) ;

        System.out.println("\n") ;

        // print out the bank accounts after applying the transactions
        System.out.println("Bank Account Balances After Processing Transactions:") ;
        System.out.println("====================================================") ;
        for (BankAccount acct : bankAccounts)
            System.out.println(acct) ;

        return ;
    }
}

//===================
// Bank Account Types
//===================

interface Checkable
{
    // tagging interface

}

interface Savable
{
    // tagging interface

}

interface Borrowable
{
    // tagging interface

}

abstract class BankAccount
{
    private String accountNumber  =   "" ;
    private double accountBalance = 0.00 ;

    public BankAccount (String pAccountNumber, double pInitialBalance)
    {
        accountNumber  = pAccountNumber  ;
        accountBalance = pInitialBalance ;

        return ;
    }

    // getters
    public String getAccountNumber  () { return accountNumber   ;}
    public double getAccountBalance () { return accountBalance  ;}

    // mutator
    boolean updateBalance (double amount)
    {
        boolean retCode = false ;

        accountBalance += amount;

        return retCode ;
    }

    // predicates
    public boolean acceptsChecks        () { return false ; }
    public boolean acceptsWires         () { return false ; }
    public boolean acceptsDeposit       () { return false ; }
    public boolean acceptsWithdrawal    () { return false ; }

    // string-izer
    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {


        return "account#: " + getAccountNumber() + "; balance: " + getAccountBalance() ;
    }
}

class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount implements Checkable
{
    public CheckingAccount (String pAccountNumber, double pInitialBalance)
    {
        super(pAccountNumber,pInitialBalance) ;

        return ;
    }

    // mutator

    boolean updateBalance (double amount)
    {
        boolean retCode = false ;

        super.updateBalance(amount);

        return retCode ;
    }



    // predicates
    @Override
    public boolean acceptsChecks        ()  { return true ; }
    @Override
    public boolean acceptsWires         ()  { return true ; }
    @Override
    public boolean acceptsDeposit       ()  { return true ; }
    @Override
    public boolean acceptsWithdrawal    ()  { return true ; }

    // string-izer
    @Override
    public String toString () { return "Checking " + super.toString() ; }
}
```

The below is the interface Transactable.

```
interface Transactable
{
    boolean applyTransaction (BankAccount pAccount) ;
}

abstract class Transaction implements Transactable
{
    private String accountNumber =   "" ;
    private double amount        = 0.00 ;

    public Transaction (String pAccountNumber, double pAmount)
    {
        accountNumber = pAccountNumber ;
        amount        = pAmount        ;

        return ;
    }

    // getters
    public String getAccountNumber  () {    return accountNumber    ;}
    public double getAmount         () {    return amount           ;}

    // string-izer
    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return "account#: " + getAccountNumber() + "; balance: " + getAmount() ;
    }

}
```

Here is the part I am having a problem with. When I try to print the error message after the checking if the balance is less than 0.00, the error message doesn't get printed immediately under the negative amount.

```
    class DepositTransaction extends Transaction
{
    public DepositTransaction (String pAccountNumber, double pAmount)
    {
        super(pAccountNumber,pAmount) ;

        return ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean applyTransaction (BankAccount pAccount)
    {
        boolean     retCode = false ;

        if(super.getAmount() > 0.00) {  
            retCode = true;     
            pAccount.updateBalance(getAmount()); 
        }
        else {  
            retCode = false;    
            System.out.println("Account doesn't accept negative amount");
        }
        return retCode ;
    }



    // string-izer
    @Override
    public String toString () { return "Deposit    " + super.toString() ; }

}
```

Here is my current screenshot

```
Checking account#: chk001; balance: 500.0
Saving account#: sav001; balance: 5000.0
Checking account#: chk002; balance: 299.0
Saving account#: sav002; balance: 9049.0


Processing Transactions:
========================
Deposit    account#: chk001; balance: 500.0
Deposit    account#: sav001; balance: 5000.0
Deposit    account#: loc001; balance: 350.0
Deposit    account#: chk001; balance: -10.0
Deposit    account#: CHK001; balance: 10.0
Account doesn't accept negative amount

There were no errors encountered during transaction processing.


Bank Account Balances After Processing Transactions:
====================================================
Checking account#: chk001; balance: 1000.0
Saving account#: sav001; balance: 10000.0
Checking account#: chk002; balance: 299.0
Saving account#: sav002; balance: 9049.0
```

I want to be able to print the error message right under the negative amount.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't start putting all your block code in one line, it's extremely hard to read.

Comment: Please don't use the `double` data type to store an amount of money.  Bad things await you if you do.

Comment: double is giving by the instructor and we cannot change it..

Comment: putting all block code in one line, I edited it.. Thanks

Comment: OK, can we see the class that has your `main` method please?

Comment: About using `double` for money - you should ask your instructor to write a program that calculates `0.1 + 0.2`.  I can guarantee that the next day, he or she will no longer be asking you to use `double` incorrectly.

Comment: It is too big, that's why I didn't want to post all the code.. It was a template..

Comment: Post the smallest amount of code that will reproduce what you see.

Comment: Well, stuff is being printed in the wrong order because you're calling stuff in the wrong order.  And you're doing it from code that you haven't shown here.  If you want help sorting this out, you need to show us the code that is _calling_ the code that you've shown here.

Comment: Alright, I posted as minimal code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this chunk in your `main` method.

```
for(Transaction t : transactionList)
    System.out.println(t);

BankAccount test = bankAccounts.get(0)
           ,test1 = bankAccounts.get(1);
Transaction t0 = transactionList.get(0)
           ,t1 = transactionList.get(1)
           ,t3 = transactionList.get(3);

t0.applyTransaction(test);
t3.applyTransaction(test);
t1.applyTransaction(test1);
```

The first two lines print out the transactions.  After that, you *apply* them, which is what makes the error messages.  So it stands to reason that you would have all your transactions printed out, and then the errors.

It seems to me that you want to rearrange this section so that each transaction in turn is printed out and then applied.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply and looking into this. Would you mind giving me a direction to which method to call after applying each transaction. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Well, the error message is actually printed by the `applyTransaction` method, so I don't think you need to call anything else.